# Curl get a description of a website but not from meta tags

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get a description of a site but **without** the use of the meta tags. Basically what I am trying to get is the first couple of sentences of a site.

So far I got this but I do not know how to get the content out the div:

```
$checkLinkOnPage = '{sitehere}';

$html = file_get_contents($checkLinkOnPage);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// find the element whose href value you want by XPath
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*');

$approvedLinks = array();

foreach($nodes as $href) {
    //Check all links see if they are valid.
    $url = $href->getAttribute('html');

    if($href->tagName == 'div'){
    //Display first div content here
    }
}
```

Comment: If you dump `$href`, you will get its type. Once you have the type, you can find the documentation for the class and see what should be used to get the contents.

Comment: That indeed gave me what I was looking for, Sadly When a site has style tags within their website than it will also show up. Any way to remove that?

Comment: You mean `<style>...</style>`? You could remove that after you get the result with regex. Not sure if you can ignore it when fetching, I haven't used much of `DOMDocument` or `xpath`.